# Place rows of numbers in order that closely match to the first row

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to build an algorithm to determine which of the following rows (below the first row) is going to be the closest match to the first row.

In my data `0` is considered the closest match possible, in fact `0` is an exact match. The farther the number gets away from `0` the less it matches. So for instance if `0` is an exact match, `1` would be the next closest number and so on. The higher the number, the less it matches.

I would like to order the rows in a way that the closest row to the first row is on top and so on. I am building this for a program that I am writing.

I was thinking (in my limited mathimatical mind) that simply adding all the numbers in the row would be a accurate way to do this and place them in that order, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

I hope what I am asking makes sense.

```
10  20  0   1   0   20  9   4   0   1   3   0   3   0   0   0   0   7   1   7


0   11  16  13  4   5   4   15  3   14  7   2   0   8   14  4   19  5   13  2
0   2   3   0   15  8   8   3   7   11  2   10  4   5   4   6   1   3   17  7
0   11  17  17  19  18  3   11  1   18  10  7   14  7   2   10  6   12  15  3
0   2   1   10  11  15  2   1   1   14  11  7   8   14  17  3   6   5   11  7
0   7   15  15  14  17  3   11  18  3   5   9   16  10  14  0   18  3   16  10
0   19  17  1   8   16  5   3   2   5   3   12  0   1   15  14  4   10  16  5
```

Comment: Suppose your top row was `0 10 20` and you had to match `10  5  0`.  Which would be better: `0  5  10` or `0  10  5`?

Comment: That's where I cant even answer that. Technically if I were to simply add up each row then they would all have the same value which would place them in the same spot. Maybe simply adding each row with a total number is my best bet.

Comment: If you do not know what your [loss function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) is, how can we judge?